# Issue with MenuFlyoutItem click event, but only "sometimes"

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have had an issue for several years that will end up driving me crazy someday.

I have a UWP app page with this button in the top bar :

```
<AppBarButton Label="Blah" Click="PageMode_Click">
    <!-- Button content, not relevant -->
</AppBarButton>
```

This is the click event handler :

```
private void PageMode_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      MenuFlyout flyout = new MenuFlyout();

      // Read_PageModeOnePage
      MenuFlyoutItem menuItem1 = new MenuFlyoutItem();
      menuItem1.Text = _resources.GetString("Read_PageModeOnePage");
      menuItem1.AddHandler(TappedEvent, new TappedEventHandler(Tapped_OnePage), true);
      flyout.Items.Add(menuItem1);

      // Read_PageModeTwoPages
      MenuFlyoutItem menuItem2 = new MenuFlyoutItem();
      menuItem2.Text = _resources.GetString("Read_PageModeTwoPages");
      menuItem2.AddHandler(TappedEvent, new TappedEventHandler(Tapped_TwoPages), true);
      flyout.Items.Add(menuItem2);

      // Read_PageModeTwoPagesCover
      MenuFlyoutItem menuItem3 = new MenuFlyoutItem();
      menuItem3.Text = _resources.GetString("Read_PageModeTwoPagesCover");
      menuItem3.AddHandler(TappedEvent, new TappedEventHandler(Tapped_TwoPagesCover), true);
      flyout.Items.Add(menuItem3);

      flyout.Placement = FlyoutPlacementMode.Bottom;
      flyout.ShowAt(sender as FrameworkElement);
    }
```

Fairly easy.

This perfectly works when i try it, and it perfectly works for almost all my users (large user base).
But then, sometimes, from some users, it does not. Either the dropdown does not appear, or it appears but when the user clicks on any entry, it doesn't do anything.

I've had maybe 100 reports about this issue over the years (out of hundreds of thousands downloads) but most likely, many users don't report it.

This is one i received yesterday :

> Hi ive been using cover for years with no problem.suddenly yesterday
>   it cant change page options..cant change the width or height or two
>   pages please help

Except i haven't done an app update in months.
For most people, it works perfectly and then out of the blue, it does this. Then someday, without an app update or the user doing anything particular, the issue will disappear.
Obviously i never witnessed it and can't reproduce it while debugging.

Has anyone ever seen something like that or any idea what to look for ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you cannot reproduce it yourself, it's really hard to help you diagnose this issue. Have you got any crash report in dev center? Have you collected the unhandled exception by using some SDKs? E.g, [App Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/crashes/uwp)

Comment: I'm using the HockeyApp SDK and have no error related to that. When my app have unhandled exceptions (which should be the case here), it crashes, i don't try to recover from it. My users don't complain about crash, just buttons that do nothing.

Comment: This issue was quite strange. If you want to solve this issue. You need to try to reproduce it, else it's hard to diagnose it. You need to collect various information. For example, the OS version, app target version, the system event viewer log etc.

Comment: I know this topic is old, but I had the same issue. The cause your app target Windows 10 version: for 1803 (10.0 compilation 17134) works Ok, but on the newer versions Tap events are not handled, ...

Comment: You're right, i noticed that a few weeks ago after i had to retarget my app to a more modern version. Even though it's old, if you put it as an answer, i'll accept it.